# Language of Stata's ADO files

Tags: stata

What language Stata ADO files are written in?

I am looking at svy.ado and curious on what language it is?

Is it something built by the Stata company?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .ado files are written in Stata's own language. An .ado file is a plain text file that contains commands understood by Stata, i.e. written in its own language. These files can also contain portions of [Mata](http://www.stata.com/stata9/mata.html) code. All the commands used in the ado files are documented in the manuals and/or in the online help.

Comment: +1 This is more accurate than the accepted answer.  Mata is a relatively recent, matrix-oriented language that supplements Stata's built-in language.  Many (most?) ado files contain little or no actual Mata.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking at Stata's [Mata](http://www.stata.com/stata9/mata.html) language.